# Main Button clickListener on bluetooth headset

Tags: android, bluetooth, headset

Проблема такая - есть гарнитура Plantronics M180. Нужно обрабатывать нажатие на главную кнопку ( сразу говорю - это не MEDIA_BUTTON, через XEVENT она тоже не отлавливается).

[image: Main Button]

В logcat нажатие на нее ничего не выводит, за исключением момента, когда идет вызов и нажатие на кнопку завершает ее, выводится следующее:

```
E/bt-rfcomm: PORT_DataInd, p_port:0xa4f3294c, p_data_co_callback is null
D/bt-btif: bta_ag_hdl_event: p_scb 0xa4f3b4e4 
D/bt-btif: AG evt (hdl 0x0001): State 2, Event 0x050b
D/bt-btif: HFP AT cmd:6 arg_type:1 arg:0 arg:
D/bt-btif: bta_ag_rfc_data, change link policy for SCO
D/bt-btif: btif_hf_upstreams_evt: event=BTA_AG_AT_CHUP_EVT
D/HeadsetStateMachine: AudioOn process message: 101, size: 1
D/HeadsetStateMachine: event type: 5
```

Какие есть способы обработать нажатие?

Answer (score 2):

Если гарнитура присоединена по hands-free профилю, то она при нажатии на эту кнопку посылает в соответствующий SPP (последовательный порт) различные AT-команды в зависимости от контекста (например, ответить на входящий звонок, повесить трубку, набрать последний набранный номер и т.д.). Эти команды обрабатывает Bluetooth hands-free AG сервис.

В качестве бредовой идеи (не уверен, что реализуемо): если гарнитуру для звонков не использовать, а использовать только кнопку, то можно попробовать отключить Phone Audio в настройках Bluetooth соединения, притвориться headset AG (он проще в реализации, чем hands-free) и соединившись по соответствующему последовательному порту получать AT-команду нажатия на кнопку.